# "Invalid Syntax" In Python Idle3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have no idea what the problem is, I've checked the code in Geany, Idle, and even the straight Python Shell, but I keep getting the same "Syntax Error" when trying to print text to the console.

Heres my complete code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

on = "On"
off = "Off"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

relay = 17

GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)

for x in range(0, 3):
    GPIO.output(relay, 1)
    print on # Where Im getting the error. I even tried 'print "on"' but still with errors
    time.sleep(4)
    GPIO.output(relay, 0)
    print off
    time.sleep(4)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? In python 3 print became a function instead of a statement.

Comment: in python 3 its `print(on)`

Comment: According to Idle, its 3. Ill try using it as a function to see if it works.

Comment: It works, but shouldn't it have thrown an error when running it through terminal using `sudo python relay.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments try it as a function. print became a function instead of a statement for example

```
teststring = "hello world"
print(teststring)
```

Comment: I did and it did work after that. I didn't realize that 2 different versions ran alongside each other

Comment: Python3 is not backwards compatible with python2 due to changes like the one you encountered so it's common to have both. Glad you've got it figured out.